# SwiftUI: Tap gesture on background blocks window resize (macOS)

Tags: macos, swiftui

I have a macOS app that uses `.windowStyle(HiddenTitleBarWindowStyle())` with a `.onTapGesture` and `.toolbar` modifier on the content view. Unfortunately the tap gesture blocks using double-tap on the toolbar to resize the window.

How can I keep the tap gesture on the background view while allowing double-tap on the toolbar to resize the window?

Here's my code:

```
struct TapGesturesMacOSApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .frame(minWidth: 400, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 300, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .onTapGesture {
                    print("Background tapped")
                }
        }
        .windowStyle(HiddenTitleBarWindowStyle())
        .windowToolbarStyle(UnifiedWindowToolbarStyle())
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(.gray)
            .toolbar {
                Button("Button") {
                    
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not zoom not because of tap gesture but because of HiddenTitleBarWindowStyle - no title bar no handler for double-tap

Comment: Please see updated code above. I oversimplified the example before and it was missing the toolbar. The double-tap seems to be received by the toolbar to resize the window but `onTapGesture` blocks this as well.